# how to display the values between two given dates in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have assigned shifts for the employee with date range.

I have to list the shifts which are assigned for a particular month, say october.

I will assign the shift with a shift start date and shift end date.

Say shift start date is oct 28 and shift end date is nov 4.

Now if want to display the shifts allocated for the month of november, the shift in this date is not being displayed.

I have checked it using

```
shiftStartDate>=oct 1
```

and

```
shiftEndDate<=oct31
```

and i also tried using between query.

This works fine if the shift start and end dates are in the same month.

Comment: Do you mean `shiftStartDate>=oct 1` and `shiftEndDate >=oct31`?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: In my table i have a employee name,shift start date and end date.for an employee name "a" the shift start date is 14/10/2018 and shift end date is 17/10/2018.   For an employee "b" shift start date is 26/10/2018 and end date is 4/11/2018. Now i have to display the shifts in the month of october(This is dynamic value).If i search for the shifts in october, the shift of employee a for all days and shift of employee b for the six days in october should be displayed

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the `BETWEEN` function in mysql to select data where a specific date is *between* 2 given dates (i.e. your *shiftStartDate* and *shiftEndDate* column).

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    example_table
WHERE
    (example_date BETWEEN shiftStartDate AND shiftEndDate);
```

example_date is the date you're checking against, e.g. *'2018-10-11'*.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **DATETIME** columns for *start* and *end* of a *shift*, you need to query for all shifts either starting within or before the current, or ending within or after the current month, e.g. to get shifts for August:

```
SELECT * FROM `shift`
  WHERE `start` <= '2018-08-31'
  AND `end` >= '2018-08-01';
```

The actual calculation of amount of days in the shift I'd do after the query.

Also make sure to use right *datetime* formats.